# Is this an appropriate place to ask for name brainstorming?

Tags: discussion

I have some brand motifs for a project I'm working on, and I want to ask the community for input on interesting names. Is English Language and Usage the best place to do so?

Comment: The Stack Exchange Q&A model, in general, is ill-suited to requests for suggestions, reviews, tips, and the like, as they are inherently subjective, evolve/devolve into open-ended lists, and otherwise do not lend themselves to a system whose scoring and voting is all designed to determine a "single most helpful" answer. Additionally, while it is possible to give thoughtful answers to requests for reviews, almost never in my experience does the OP provide adequate context, making every answer a guessing game as to what the OP is actually seeking.

Comment: I agree that there's probably nowhere on the whole StackExchange network for that kind of question (it's just not how the model works). I will recommend the BabyNameWizard fora as a good place for this kind of naming brainstorming. Don't let the name put you off; the blog is a statistics-driven exploration of naming trends in society, and the discussion fora have a high standard for both civility and evidence-based advice. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Naming of actual human babies is the most common topic, but any naming question is welcomed (there's an entire sub-forum for naming of fictional characters and I've also seen discussions on a variety of topics such as adults re-naming themselves, naming of online businesses, and, most recently, naming a couple of chickens).

Comment: [Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15538/2085).

Answer (score 9):

This would not be a good place to ask. The Help Center page "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" says questions about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" are out of scope for this site.

Speaking more generally, brainstorming questions of any kind are generally a poor fit for the Stack Exchange format and culture. A common viewpoint is that a Stack Exchange question ought to have some kind of single "best" answer that is not primarily opinion-based and that will be useful to future site visitors.

Comment: This begs the question: could this community benefit from an `opinions` or suggestions site? Maybe not, but where could this be debated?

Comment: @user: I think the Meta Stack Exchange site would be the place for discussions like that, but they've already happened years ago: see for example [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s) and all of the other [Meta posts that are linked to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/57383?lq=1)